# Does Azure Cosmos DB - Mongo API support aggregation

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, azure-cosmosdb

I was looking to use cosmosdb to store time series data laid out in a [document-centric design](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb).  Using the official mongodb driver I tried to write some simple aggregation statements; however, I received errors stating that $unwind and $group were not supported.  Given that cosmosdb was touted as a drop-in replacement to mongodb did I miss a step or is aggregation not a supported feature.

```
retrieve.Aggregate().Unwind(i => i.Observations).Group(new BsonDocument {
        {"_id", "$Observations.Success"},
        {"avg", new BsonDocument{
        {"$avg", "$Observations.Duration"}
        }}
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Given that what would be happening "underneath" is that the wire protocol issued from the "driver" is being "mapped" to specific CosmosDB methods, then such specific errors would indicate that it is not supported. A quick bit of "search engine fu" shows only recent additions to allow "SQL aggregation" and no documentation at all to suggest there is any support for MongoDB aggregation. So unless very recently added, then no documentation coupled with errors reinforcing the case would mean "No". I think the specific errors are actually the concrete thing here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I suspect that as well.  Call me naive but I was hoping I just did something wrong.

Comment: @Tedford - Aggregation pipeline is now supported. See my related answer (along with link to published list of supported features).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of November 2017, Cosmos DB's MongoDB API now supports aggregation pipeline, including all of the pipeline stages identified in your original question (`$unwind`, `$group`).

Specifics of supported features are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support).

Answer (score 8):

Given the comment from @neillunn and the lack of any documentation to that affect is seems that the aggregation functions for cosmosdb are not supported via the mongo API.  It appears that the [intention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates) is to use the cosmosdb Documentdb API SQL syntax for aggregates.

**LINQ Syntax**

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("https://<account>.documents.azure.com"),<password>);

    // issue query
    var documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("Prod", "retrieve");
    var date = "20161011".Dump("Date");


    var max = client.CreateDocumentQuery<ObservationDocument>(documentUri)
          .Where(i => i.Id == date)
          .SelectMany(i => i.observations)
          .Max(i => i.Duration);
```

**SQL syntax**

```
// explicit query
var spec = new SqlQuerySpec("select value count(o.duration) from days d join o in d.observations where d._id = @id");
spec.Parameters = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameterCollection();
spec.Parameters.Add(new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameter("@id", "20161010"));
client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("Prod", "retrieve"), spec).Dump("As query");
```